# Is there a way to pass multiple values into a CSV file, based on the output of a linux script

Tags: linux, bash, csv, unix, md5sum

I have written a small script that will take the users input and then generate the md5sum values for it

```
count = 0
echo "Enter number of records"
read number
while [ $count -le $number ]
do
    echo "Enter path"
    read path
    echo "file name"
    read file_name
    md5sum $path"/"$filename  #it shows the md5sum value and path+filename
    ((count++))
done
```

How can I pass these values ( *path,file name, and md5sums* ) to CSV file. ( assuming the user chooses to enter more than 1 record)

The **output** should be like

```
/c/training,sample.txt,34234435345346549862123454651324      #placeholder values
/c/file,text.sh,4534534534534534345345435342342
```

Comment: perhaps something like: `echo "${path},${file_name},"$(md5sum "${path}/${filename}") >> my.csv`

Comment: @markp-fuso. It does work. I am sorry but I should have mentioned this in the original question but is there a way to create a new CSV file each time the script is run. I have edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactively prompting for the number of files to process is just obnoxious. Change the script so it accepts the files you want to process as command-line arguments.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
md5sum "$@" |
sed 's%^\([0-9a-f]*\)  \(\(.*\)/\)?\([^/]*\)$%\3,\4,\1%'
```

There are no Bash-only constructs here, so I switched the shebang to `/bin/sh`; obviously, you are still free to use Bash if you like.

There is a reason `md5sum` prints the checksum *before* the path name. The reordered output will be ambiguous if you have file names which contain commas (or newlines, for that matter). Using CSV format is actually probably something you should avoid if you can; Unix tools generally work better with simpler formats like tab-delimited (which of course also breaks if you have file names with tabs in them).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than prompting the user for both a path to a directory and the name of a file in that directory, you could prompt for a full path to the file.  You can then extract what you need from that path using [bash string manipulations](https://linuxgazette.net/18/bash.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

function calc_md5() {
    local path="${1}"
    if [[ -f "${path}" ]] ; then
        echo "${path%/*}, ${path##*/}, $(md5sum ${path} | awk '{ print $1 }')"
    else 
        echo "
            x - Script requires path to file.
            Usage: $0 /path/to/file.txt
        "
        exit 1
    fi
}

calc_md5 "$@"
```

Usage example:

```
$ ./script.sh /tmp/test/foo.txt
/tmp/test, foo.txt, b05403212c66bdc8ccc597fedf6cd5fe
```

Comment: when i ran this, the git bash just shuts down. New to Linux here, so not sure why that happens